# Find & remove duplicate strings via Unix shell script. How to?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm a Unix shell script newbie. I know several different way to find duplicates. But can't find a simple way to remove duplicates while maintaining original order (since using sort -u loses original order).

Example: script called `dedupe.sh`

sample run:

`dedupe.sh`

```
cat dog cat bird fish bear dog
```

results in: `cat dog bird fish bear`

Comment: This isn't the sort of thing shell scripting is designed for.  Which shell are you using?  You should probably add a perl tag to this, someone will pop by with a solution in perl.

Comment: Is this in a file?  Use `uniq` if it is.

Answer (score 2):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
$ printf '%s\n' cat dog cat bird fish bear dog | awk '!arr[$1]++'
cat
dog
bird
fish
bear
```

or

```
$ echo 'cat dog cat bird fish bear dog' | awk '!arr[$1]++' RS=" "
```

or

```
$ printf '%s\n' cat dog cat bird fish bear dog | sort -u
```

If it works in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell), it will works in a script =)

Answer (score 1):

Did you say Perl?

```
perl -e 'while($_=shift@ARGV){$seen{$_}++||print}print"\n" ' \
cat dog cat bird fish bear dog
```

Equivalently, `dedupe.pl` contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while ($w = shift @ARGV) {
    $seen{$w}++ || print "$w";
}
print "\n";
```

Now `chmod u+x dedupe.pl` and:

```
./dedupe.pl cat dog cat bird fish bear dog
```

Either way, output is as desired.

```
cat dog bird fish bear
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh perl... the write-only language. :)

As long as you're calling out to another scripting language, might as well consider something readable. :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts ARGV.uniq.join(' ')
```

which means:

```
puts = "print whatever comes next"
ARGV = "input argument array"
uniq = "array method to perform the behavior you're looking for and remove duplicates"
join(' ') = "join with spaces instead of default of newline. Not necessarily needed if you're piping to something else"
```